# How to Write VBA code for adjusting line arrow : double length as per image inserted?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to do in the PowerPoint through VBA is that if I had image in one presentation and after running the macro the arrow shape (in PowerPoint has name of the shape "line arrow: double") automatically comes and it should automatically adjust its length as per the image
pl. find the attached image to get clear idea what I am trying to convey

All the positive responses are welcomed.

Thanks & Regards,

Shubham Mehta.   [image for explaining my macro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtAHU.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code (Edit2):

```
Option Explicit

Const OUTLINE_LEN = 25      ' length of the sidelines
Const OUTLINE_RATE = 0.7    ' the place of the arrowed line along sidelines
Const LINE_WEIGHT = 2
Const MARK = "#Dimension#"    'For example, for further delete or change color of the measurement shapes

Sub Measurement()   'launch this
    Dim shp As Shape, sh As Shape, sl As Slide
    Dim a(1 To 3), i As Integer
    
    Set sl = ActiveWindow.View.Slide    'get the active slide
    
    ' if any picture is being selected, get it else get the first picture from the active slide
    If ActiveWindow.Selection.Type <> ppSelectionNone Then
        If ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Type = msoPicture Then
            Set shp = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
        End If
    Else
        For Each sh In sl.Shapes
            If sh.Type = msoPicture Then
                Set shp = sl.Shapes(1)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If
    
    ' if no pictures then exit
    If shp Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No one picture exists on the active slide", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "Sub SizeArrow()"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' make all the possible dimensions
    For i = 1 To 2
        makeDimension shp, i
    Next
End Sub

Sub makeDimension(shp As Shape, direction As Integer)   ' direction = 1 (top), 2 (left), 3 (bottom), 4 (right)
    Dim a(1 To 3)
    
    With shp.Parent.Shapes
        ' create 3 lines depends direction and put their names into array a
        Select Case direction
            Case 1
                a(1) = .AddLine(shp.Left, shp.Top, shp.Left, shp.Top - OUTLINE_LEN).Name
                a(2) = .AddLine(shp.Left + shp.Width, shp.Top, shp.Left + shp.Width, shp.Top - OUTLINE_LEN).Name
                a(3) = .AddLine(shp.Left, shp.Top - OUTLINE_LEN * OUTLINE_RATE, shp.Left + shp.Width, shp.Top - OUTLINE_LEN * OUTLINE_RATE).Name
            Case 2
                a(1) = .AddLine(shp.Left, shp.Top, shp.Left - OUTLINE_LEN, shp.Top).Name
                a(2) = .AddLine(shp.Left, shp.Top + shp.Height, shp.Left - OUTLINE_LEN, shp.Top + shp.Height).Name
                a(3) = .AddLine(shp.Left - OUTLINE_LEN * OUTLINE_RATE, shp.Top, shp.Left - OUTLINE_LEN * OUTLINE_RATE, shp.Top + shp.Height).Name
            Case 3
                a(1) = .AddLine(shp.Left, shp.Top + shp.Height, shp.Left, shp.Top + shp.Height + OUTLINE_LEN).Name
                a(2) = .AddLine(shp.Left + shp.Width, shp.Top + shp.Height, shp.Left + shp.Width, shp.Top + shp.Height + OUTLINE_LEN).Name
                a(3) = .AddLine(shp.Left, shp.Top + shp.Height + OUTLINE_LEN * OUTLINE_RATE, shp.Left + shp.Width, shp.Top + shp.Height + OUTLINE_LEN * OUTLINE_RATE).Name
            Case 4
                a(1) = .AddLine(shp.Left + shp.Width, shp.Top, shp.Left + shp.Width + OUTLINE_LEN, shp.Top).Name
                a(2) = .AddLine(shp.Left + shp.Width, shp.Top + shp.Height, shp.Left + shp.Width + OUTLINE_LEN, shp.Top + shp.Height).Name
                a(3) = .AddLine(shp.Left + shp.Width + OUTLINE_LEN * OUTLINE_RATE, shp.Top, shp.Left + shp.Width + OUTLINE_LEN * OUTLINE_RATE, shp.Top + shp.Height).Name
            Case Else: Exit Sub
        End Select
    End With
    
    ' set arrows to the 3rd line
    With shp.Parent.Shapes(a(3)).Line
        .BeginArrowheadStyle = msoArrowheadOpen
        .EndArrowheadStyle = msoArrowheadOpen
    End With
    
    ' group all the added lines and set color and thikness
    With shp.Parent.Shapes.Range(a).Group
        .AlternativeText = MARK   ' mark the measurement shape
        With .Line
        .ForeColor.RGB = vbRed
        .Weight = LINE_WEIGHT
        End With
    End With
End Sub

' Bonus Sub for cleaning it all up :)
Sub deleteDimensionsFromPresentetion()  'deletes all previously created measurement shape from active presentetion
    Dim sl As Slide, i As Integer
    For Each sl In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For i = sl.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
            If sl.Shapes(i).AlternativeText = MARK Then sl.Shapes(i).Delete
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot it work for me can you do one favour on me could me also help me mow to insert this type of arrows in vertical direction (means along the width of the image) while this program inserts the arrow in the horizontal (means along the length of the image)

Comment: @ShubhamMehta see the solution (Edit2)

Comment: Thanks a Lot.... I am so glad and thank you so much I was trying but I was not able to make it this VBA code works for me.
Once Again thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Record a macro. I'm not sure if recording is available in ppt so record it in excel. It should move to ppt fairly well.

Lisa